# bash one-liner loop over directories throws errors

Tags: bash, tar, scripting

I'm trying to build a bash one-liner to loop over the directories within the current directory and tar the content into unique tars, using the directory name as the tar file name.  I've got the basics working (finding the directory names, and tarring them up with those names) but my loop tosses some error messages and I can't understand where it's getting the commands its trying to run.

Here's the mostly-working one-liner:

```
for f in `ls -d */`; do `tar -czvvf ${f%/}.tar.gz $f`;done
```

The "strange" output is:

```
-bash: drwxrwxr-x: command not found
-bash: drwxr-xr-x: command not found
-bash: drwxr-xr-x: command not found
-bash: drwxrwxr-x: command not found
```

What portion of the command that I'm running do I not understand and that's generating that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the backtics around your `tar` command.  You also might want to pipe the `ls` through `xargs` to  make sure bash picks up all the directories correctly:

```
for f in `ls -d */ | xargs`; do tar -cvzf ${f%/}.tar.gz $f; done
```

The backticks are capturing the ouput of `tar` and attempting to execute that as a command in each iteration of the loop.  The first thing `tar` prints when you use a -v option is the permissions on each file (e.g. the `drwxrwxr-x`).  In this case, you want bash to *execute* the tar command, not capture the output.

Comment: Most excellent - thanks for both the resolution, and more importantly for explaining the what and why.  Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**bjlaub** is correct regarding the backticks around `tar`, however you don't need to use `ls`:

```
for file in */
```

will do the trick and will properly handle directory names with spaces.

Comment: Indeed you're correct.  Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good, but I wanted to add another option in case you need to get just directories and not symbolic links, etc:

```
for f in `find -maxdepth 1 -type d` | do -cvzf ${f%/}.tar.gz $f; done
```

Hope this helps!